# Binding Paramaters in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a dynamic query builder.

I have two bits of code.

The first bit, creates the PDO object (I know this works) and then runs the search function in my querybuilder.

```
include 'core/database/dbloader.php';
$domainName = "lomcn.org";

$query = new dbquery(Connection::make($dbconfig['domainhistory']));
$query->search('dns','domain',$domainName);
```

The search function is -

```
public function search($table,$field,$domainName)
{
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} LIKE :domain");
    $statement->bindParam(":domain",$domainName);
    $statement->execute();

    return ($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```

This does not return ANY errors, however no data is displayed. Am I missing something? The purpose is you should be able to run

```
$query->search(table,field,value);
```

and it just works.

Comment: Do you have an example of what would pass through for `$domainName` ?

Comment: `$domainName` has wildcards, or is looking for an exact match?

Comment: What should it do? You don't print anything to the screen or something.

Comment: JFYI: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: As of your question, to get an answer you have to provide a [Complete Working Example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: $domainName = "lomcn.org";  would be looking for an exact match.  Pretty sure return ($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));  should just dump everything to the screen for now? can organize it later.

Comment: The assembled query works on direct DB interaction? `SELECT * FROM dns WHERE domain LIKE 'lomcn.org'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course nothing is being displayed, you have not told it to display anything. No echo command. No print command. Nothing.

Instead of `$query->search(table,field,value);` You could try something similar to;

```
foreach ($query->search(table,field,value) as $row) {
    print $row['DB_COLUMN_1'];
    print $row['DB_COLUMN_2'];
    print $row['DB_COLUMN_3'];
}
```

Also, if you are using a LIKE clause in your SQL statement you NEED to use percentage signs as wildcards or the LIKE clause wont work as expected. So unless you are looking for an exact match, change your bindParam to:

```
$statement->bindParam(":domain", "%" . $domainName . "%");
```

Comment: You are right I'm an idiot. I presumed returning it would dump it to the screen, but it didnt.